# Careers 2.0 :: Large image source for small thumbnails slows down frontpage loading

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs, design, homepage

This is my first ever post on meta, my apologies in advance if this is not the right place to express such concerns but this is where the feedback button led me to. The problem is very minor and I don't think it deserves a whole post, but I saw no other options.

## **The problem:**

Now before I explain, I'd like to note this is not a huge issue of any kind, but I believe it could be improved.

I noticed recently that you've added an **explore cities** section on the front-page with little beautiful thumbnails for every city. However, their loading is very noticeable as a vertical bar filling itself, my connection is not slow (100 mbps) but maybe the distance from your closest data center and international lines are affecting it as it takes about **400 to 900** ms per image to load.

I've snapped a little GIF during the loading process to express visually what I mean. Sometimes they load relatively fast, sometimes it's very noticeable.

[image: Dynamically scaled images loading]

**Thumbnail size**: 180x83

**Raw image size:** 975x450

Unless I am missing something and you need the larger images getting dynamically scaled down through CSS, I believe those thumbnails can be pre-generated appropriately through your CDN to avoid the visual slow-down for users with slow connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out - we're going to be using optimized image sizes for the thumbnails for these views now.

Comment: It was marked as completed but it is not, or it takes some time for the changes to make it to the production version? Just asking before I mark this as answer and close the question.

Comment: Looks like it actually just to pushed to production.